# Access array for update Laravel + vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a **vue** template and I'm trying to access the `pets` array.

[image]

This is my code

```
foreach ($request->pets as $pet) {
    $pet = $client->pets()->find($pet)->first();
    $pet->name = request('pets[].name');
    $pet->update();
}
```

If I hardcode a `name`, it updates. How do I access pet objects?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your loop here, setting both the `foreach()` variable as `$pet`, and the `Pet` model as `$pet`.

Try:

```
foreach ($request->pets as $pet) {
    $p = $client->pets()->find($pet)->first();
    $p->name = $pet['name'];
    $p->save();
}
```

Also, you can use the `->save()` method here instead of `->update()`.